# Use python script to request and receive data from C++ Program

Tags: python, c++, tcp

Hi there I am looking for a way to simply run a python script that talks to a running C++ program, that C++ would then spit something back out for the Python script in the form of, say, a string... Any ideas on this would be great, I've seen that zeromq is a possibility but I'm not sure where to start with that. I have read briefly about pipes but I also don't have a clue how to use those.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Sorry the question seemed vague I've only posted on here twice and these are my first responses, but the end goal is to get a python webscript that I can pass a URL variable of a string to and the python script will then check that string and depending on what that string is then the python will send a string to C++ which will then send a string back to the WebScript so that the script can print that string.

Thanks

Comment: What communication options does the "c++ program" even offer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) to call c++ function from python directly.Just check their website for simple examples of how this is done.This is to be done if you are not communicating to another process. If you want to communicate to other processes then some MQ would work. https://kafka.apache.org/ is a distributed one.

Comment: The question is way to vague to say anything useful, but it does state that this is a running c++ program - so its a separate process and swig doesn't help.